# Remove duplicates based on 2nd column condition

Tags: r

I am trying to remove duplicate rows from a data frame based on the max value on a different column

So, for the data frame:

```
df<-data.frame (rbind(c("a",2,3),c("a",3,4),c("a",3,5),c("b",1,3),c("b",2,6),c("r",4,5))
  colnames(df)<-c("id","val1","val2")

id val1 val2

  a    2    3

  a    3    4

  a    3    5

  b    1    3

  b    2    6

  r    4    5
```

I would like to keep remove all duplicates by id with the condition that for the corresponding rows they do not have the maximum value for val2.

Thus the data frame should become:

```
  a    3    5

  b    2    6

  r    4    5
```

-> remove all a duplicates but keep row with the max value for df$val2 for subset(df, df$id=="a")

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using `base R`.  Here, the columns are `factors`.  Make sure to convert it to `numeric`

```
 df$val2 <- as.numeric(as.character(df$val2))
 df[with(df, ave(val2, id, FUN=max)==val2),]
 #  id val1 val2
 #3  a    3    5
 #5  b    2    6
 #6  r    4    5
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    filter(val2==max(val2))
 #   id val1 val2
 #1  a    3    5
 #2  b    2    6
 #3  r    4    5
```

Comment: You''ll probably need to add `mutate(val2 = as.numeric(as.character(val2))) %>%` to your `dplyr` solution

Comment: @David Arenburg  I used the converted `df` from the previous solution.  Yes, you are right about it, but I am guessing that the OP might have made a mistake in constructing the example.

Comment: (+1) for posting both of these one split second before I was going to :)

Comment: This works great, but if I have millions of rows with very few duplicates, it takes quite a while - that is the code will also have to create millions of groups that consist of only 1 element. Is there any way to improve the solution in such a case?

Comment: @user3032689  In that case, `df %>% group_by(id) %>% arrange(desc(val2)) %>% slice(1L)` should be faster.

Comment: Thanks @akrun. Do you also know the solution in `datatable`? I am not using `plyr` atm and probably it's a one liner as well?

Comment: @user3032689 With data.table `setDT(df)[order(-val2), head(.SD, 1), id]`

Answer (score 8):

One possible way is to use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[which.max(val2)], by = id]
##    id val1 val2
## 1:  a    3    5
## 2:  b    2    6
## 3:  r    4    5
```

Comment: This is great!Thank you!  However, I am using the R integration with Spotfire and  there have been issues with installing packages, compatibility between OS, versions, software version, statistical services etc and it would be nice to have a solution that does not require additional libraries or loops .

Comment: Very nice! but there is a faster way using  setDT(df)[df[, .I[which.max(val2)], by = id]$V1]. Hope it helps for larger datasets.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I hope your data is really set up

```
df <- data.frame (id = c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 2), "r"),
                  val1 = c(2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4), val2 = c(3, 4, 5, 3, 6, 5))
```

You could do a `split`-`unsplit`

```
> unsplit(lapply(split(df, df$id), function(x) {
      if(nrow(x) > 1) {
          x[duplicated(x$id) & x$val2 == max(x$val2),]
      } else {
          x
      }
  }), levels(df$id))
#   id val1 val2
# 3  a    3    5
# 5  b    2    6
# 6  r    4    5
```

You can also use `Reduce(rbind, ...)` or `do.call(rbind, ...)` in place of `unsplit`

Answer (score 1):

Another one

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>%
         slice(which.max(val2))

  id   val1  val2
   a    3     5
   b    2     6
   r    4     5
```